# Self not defined?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a login view that checks if login users are either a client or pilot and redirect them appropriately but i keep getting self not defined error. Any help will be appreciated.

**views.py**

```
def signin (request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']

    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')
        if user.role == 'client':
            def ef (self):
                return redirect(reverse('dashboard', kwargs={"pk": self.pk}))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('pilot_dashboard', kwargs={"pk": self.pk}))
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect ('login')

 else:
    return render (request, 'accounts/signin.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following in your code:

```
    if user.role == 'client':
        def ef (self):
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard', kwargs={"pk": self.pk}))
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('pilot_dashboard', kwargs={"pk": self.pk}))
```

The `def ef (self)` is not needed and also doesn't work in this way. Just remove that one.

Furthermore you are then using `self.pk` which is not possible there. If you want to access the users `pk`, just use `user.pk` as your user is saved in the variable `user`, not `self`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I removed **def ef (self)** and added user.self as recommended but it now makes it possible for client to login to pilot dashboard which is not what i want.

Comment: @flow I hope it's just a typo with `user.self` here;) In the `client`/`dashboard`-views you will also have to validate the user for the existing group. Your `signin`-view handles the redirect on login but if the user is allowed to show the redirected page has to be done there. (e.g. he could just add `pilot_` to the url in the browser)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need construction:

```
def ef (self):
```

Actually, you don't have to return function, you have to return redirect.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I removed **def ef (self)** but still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following change should solve your problem.

```py
def signin (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            messages.success(request, 'You are now logged in')
            if user.role == 'client':
                return redirect(reverse('dashboard', kwargs={"pk": user.pk}))
            else:
                return redirect(reverse('pilot_dashboard', kwargs={"pk": user.pk}))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
            return redirect ('login')

    else:
        return render (request, 'accounts/signin.html')
```

Main problem was here is no `self` instance. this is user i guess.